# SSH Error: No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh

On an Ubuntu 16.04 system on Google GCP, I need to create a new user `hello` and allow other users to SSH to the system as user `hello` using their current SSH keys.

Here's what I did to add my SSH public key to `hello`'s `authorized_keys`:

```
sudo useradd -m hello -s /bin/bash
sudo mkdir /home/hello/.ssh
sudo chown hello:hello -R /home/hello
sudo chmod 777 /home/hello/.ssh
sudo cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >> /home/hello/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 700 /home/hello/.ssh/
sudo chmod 600 /home/hello/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Problem:** When I try to SSH to the server as `hello` user, I get the error

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent public key)

`/var/log/auth.log` contains

> Nov  4 17:37:05 hello sshd[27298]: error: Received disconnect from 174.63.124.9 port 62346:14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
>   Nov  4 17:37:05 hello sshd[27298]: Disconnected from 174.63.124.9 port 62346 [preauth]

What went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Who owns authorized keys , what ssh command, and what ssh server config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the owner of the file `authorized_keys` after it is created, since it will be owned by the user running the script.

Adding this as last line to your script should do the trick.

`sudo chown hello:hello /home/hello/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in server site this user "hello"  is blacklisted

try this:

```
grep **AllowUsers** /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

or this:

```
grep **DenyUsers** /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

try with groups too  `AllowGroups` and `DenyGroups`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the /home directory permissions. It should be

- `drwxr-xr-x.   9 root root   113 Jun 28 22:57 home`

and then your home directory detail:

- `drwxr-----   5  user group   124 May 18 17:00 User
   drwx------  2 user group   29 May 18 12:05 .ssh
   -rw-------  1 user group 2235 Jun 28 23:09 authorized_keys`

**My error messages in logs**

**/var/log/auth.log** > sshd[22565]: error: Received disconnect from X.X.X.X: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]

**On client side**

`ssh user@X.X.X.X
  Permission denied (publickey).
ssh -vvv user@X.X.X.X
  ...
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
  Permission denied (publickey).`


**On server side**

- `service sshd stop`
- run sshd debug mode:
- `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd`

  `...
        debug1: trying public key file /home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
        debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
   ...`